# Can "sciò" be used for person? If so, in which cases can it be considered acceptable?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

I remember my grandmother saying *sciò* to keep away an animal that was getting too close to something or somebody, whatever it was a cat, a chicken, or a dog.

Can that exclamation be used also for a person? If the answer is positive, in which cases is that acceptable?

Comment: Bonus: "sciò!", along with "via!" is often depicted in the signs in front of the Zio Paperone (Scrooge McDuck?)  Deposito (Money Bin?) http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100803194146/paperpedia/it/images/3/3e/Deposito.gif

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've heard it used even for people, but only in familiar or informal contexts; typically it's used to shoo (!) away children or people engaging in child-like disturbing behavior.

Unless clearly joking (at least to some extent), I would say it's rude to use it with adult people who aren't intentionally bothering somebody: the "target" of the *sciò* is put at the same level of an annoying animal or child, and is told to shoo away without even bothering to give a reason for that.